# In Android Intent why we write ActivityTwo.class in second argument?

Tags: android, android-intent

Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityTwo.class);
startActivity(i);

Why ActivityTwo.class??

Why not .java please explain
Thank you

Comment: Because the parameter requires a class, not a file...

Comment: Thank You so much for clearing my confusion. I will read from those links for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second parameter in the Intent call is a component. We are actually setting a component name as the second parameter which is a class name. You can read about component here in this link. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html

Answer (score 0):

This provides a convenient way to create an intent that is intended to execute a hard-coded class name, rather than relying on the system to find an appropriate class for you; see [setComponent(ComponentName)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setComponent(android.content.ComponentName)) for more information.